# shell_exec() and exec() Doesn't Show The Output

Tags: php, file-io, exec, shell-exec

`shell_exec()`:

I'm doing a PHP site that uses a `shell_exec()` function like this:

```
$file = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$output = shell_exec("leaf $file");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Where leaf is a program that is located in the same directory of my script, but when I tried to run this script on the server, I just got nothing.

---

`exec()`:

If I try by using `exec()` like this:

```
exec("sh " . getcwd() . "leaf -h", &$output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(&$output);
echo "</pre>";
```

I got this:

```
Array
(
)
```

If I do the same thing, but using `echo` instead of `print_r`, I got only this: `Array`

What I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the full path with your "leaf" reference?

```
$output = shell_exec("/var/local/leaf $file");
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already done this: `$output = shell_exec("sh " . getcwd() . "/leaf $file");`, but I got nothing too.

Comment: Can you try just using a static path and see if that changes anything?  getcwd() would most likely get the CWD from Apache which is probably different than what you're thinking.  You might also consult the error_log for clues.

Comment: I've put the static path and I still got nothing.

Comment: Do you think that this is an issue of the "leaf" command not being executed or the output not being captured?  Maybe there's an issue with this "leaf" command an the output from it?  It's hard to speculate with any certainty in generalities but I feel your pain.

Comment: I've tried `ls` and it worked, but any other programs that I try that aren't on the `PATH` I get nothing.

Comment: Even if I add the directory to the `PATH`, I still got nothing. **:'(**

Comment: The only other place I'd look would be the error_log.  If there's nothing there, then it would suggest to me a server configuration issue and that could really be like searching for a needle in a haystack.

Have you searched the web and other sources for a PHP equivalent library for whatever script this "leaf" command purports too?